# "no shared cipher" error when trying SSL connection from Android to server

Tags: java, android, ssl, tcl

Whenever I try to connect with SSL from an Android App to a Tcl server, the connection fails. Both systems seem to have a very long list of supported ciphers, but they name them quite differently, so I cannot really tell which is which.

the Tcl error message is:

```
SSL channel "sock7": error: no shared cipher
```

the Android error message is:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer
```

Is there any hope to find a solution for this?

The Tcl code is:

```
package require tls
::tls::init  -ssl2 0 -ssl3 1 -tls1 1 -require 0 -request 0
set mainSock [::tls::socket -server serve 1200]
```

The Android Code is:

```
import javax.net.SocketFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;

SocketFactory sf = SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) sf.createSocket("server.de", 1200);
```

Comment: I this all the code? Dou you configure any certificates on the server side or do you expect Android to use anonymous authentication? The latter might fail.

Comment: Which version of the tls package are you using? Which cypher suites are enabled in Java? (This is an area in flux right now because people are shifting to TLSv1 from SSLv3 due to recently discovered protocol weaknesses, which will make matching things up rather messy for a while.)

Comment: @Steffen Yes, that's all the code regarding the connection. There is no authentication involved, just setting up a connection. I don't want to use any certificates yet.

Comment: @Donal I am using tls 1.6 on tcl 8.6.1 (and also tried 1.5 on tcl on 8.5.8)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everybody for help. I have figured it out with your answers.

It seems impossible to use Tcl as a server without any certificates. Not even another Tcl script can connect to the server without certificates. The client can leave out the validity checking, but the server must provide a certificate. **This is not stated clearly in the documentation!**

Now I can establish a connection with a home-made certificate as stated on page http://wiki.tcl.tk/15244

Unfortunately, I don't (yet) know how to tell Android to not check the validity for now (like -require 0 in Tcl). Maybe I'll just import my own CA into the Android device. Otherwise, I would have to buy a certificate signed by an official CA. Some time in the future, I'll have to do this anyway.

Comment: Get yourself a certificate signed by a cheap public CA. It won't take you long or cost you much at all (for a single host certificate) and it's by far the easiest way to work. No recommendations on CAs though; the one I use at work is because we've got a special deal…

Answer (score 0):

Cipher suites can be named differently but they share the same "value". The error message is explicit in stating that there are no common cipher suites. This could be due to many reasons. Some but not all:

1. The SSL certificate on the server is based on say ECC versus RSA (different algorithms).
2. For the TLS protocol enabled, the ends do not have any common cipher suites.

List of cipher suites with their "values":

https://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/tls-parameters.xhtml#tls-parameters-4

Comment: This is the information I get from Tcl and Android about the ciphers: http://plausibolo.de/tmp/tls-ssl-ciphers.pdf

Comment: Tcl server is pretty limited in terms of cipher suites as well as being outdated as well. Is there a way that a newer version would have more cipher suites? Am not versed in tcl as a disclaimer. Also it seems that ssl v3 and tls v1 are enabled on the tcl server correct?

Comment: Also try connecting with OpenSSL s_client and see if that works and with what cipher suite? This is to make sure that the server configuration is not the issue

Answer (score 0):

Since your SSL server does not use any certificates the only possible ciphers are anonymous ciphers suites. Since these are insecure (open to man-in-the-middle attacks) they are not enabled by default for SSLSockets. 
Thus the client will only announce support for cipher suites with proper authentication and it will not offer any ciphers usable with your TCL server. This causes the "no shared cipher" error.

If you really want to use such an insecure setup you might have a look at http://www.nickoh.com/emacs_files/ssl-examples/LdapTlsExample.java.txt for an example which uses anonymous cipher suites together with SSLSockets (I did not check if the example works, it as just one of the first hits when searching for support of anon cipher suites).